# PHP Proxy for big files (Relaying)

Tags: php, file, proxy, download

I am looking for a PHP function, which gets a file from a web server, while outputting it.
As its a big file it should always output a chunk eg 1kb once it's loaded and not load the whole file and then output it.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question you want to offer a file download that doesn't eat all your ram, even for large files? If so, this is possible with the standard php file reading functions; like this:

```
$chunk_size=1024;
$file_name='read.txt';
//open file
$file=fopen($file_name,'r');

if($file!=false){
    //while we haven't reached the end

    while(!feof($file)){
        //read chunk and output
        $line=fread($file,$chunk_size);
        echo $line;
    }

    fclose($file);
}
else{
     //error reading file
}
```

You can wrap this in a PHP function if you like. It should be noted that I literally wrote this code into stack overflow so it is untested. But it should give you an idea on the theory.

Hope this helps, Ryan

/** Edit **/

P.s This code does not include the code to force a download - If you also require this, please let me know. Also, this should work with remote files however, there is a setting in your PHP.ini file which allows or prevents this action (allow_url_fopen).